# Matlab: how to get the commandline to the new 2013 UI?

Tags: macos, matlab, user-interface, usability

I changed to the newest Matlab and it has totally new GUI where I lost the command line after some working. How can I get it back and where is it? The old help in top bar does not return it like in the earlier version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, open the "HOME" menu, select somewhat on the right "Layout", and there "Default" or "Command Window only". However, it appears you don't even have the "HOME" menu anymore. Restart Matlab?

Comment: +1 restart worked but I cannot understand what the latter mode was, I had very important debugging in the process where I had stopped to a breakpoint. I think the main window may have been somehow hidden, dunno -- could not find it. Wish there was some combinations of keys to get the commandline or home visible.

Comment: Never happened to me. I just tried to close the main window while having an undocked editor window, to reproduce your situation, but Matlab just quit completely.

Comment: @A.Donda: The "Home" tab is only present within the Command window, not the Editor window. And of course the actual OS X menu bar is not used for anything. hhh: It's strange that your command window could disappear like that because closing it manually (red "x" in top left) promptly quits Matlab (yet more un-Maclike behavior that has bitten me numerous times).

Comment: @horchler: Not to be nitpicking – whom am I kidding, of course to be nitpicking ;-) – in an undocked Editor, there are the buttons EDITOR/PUBLISH/VIEW, and no HOME. But in an undocked Command window, there are no buttons at all. That window that contains HOME, and which strangely possesses the ability to contain no other panels at all, appears to be called "MATLAB". It is possible to close an undocked Command window without quitting, but then it just pops back up embedded in the "MATLAB window". What is strange is that hhh managed to lose this MATLAB window without quitting. (checked on Linux)

Comment: @A.Donda: Ahh. I see. I use my command window within the "MATLAB" window (with "HOME" etc. tabs). There isn't even an undock button in that case -you have to convert to some other layout to pop out the command window as a totally independent window.